# Disable session in Laravel

Tags: php, session, laravel, laravel-5

I am developing stateless resful API application, so I do not need sessions at all.

I removed a line with `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,` from `protected $middleware = [];` in `\app\Http\Kernel.php` I have also removed `SESSION_DRIVE` from `.env` file. But I am getting following error:

```
RuntimeException in Request.php line 756: Session store not set on request.
```

How can I turn off sessions in Laravel 5?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Remove the `Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken` and `Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession` classes from your middleware too. These features require sessions.

Not required but I'd also probably suggest setting your session driver to `array`, just so that if any features you are using require the sessions feature they can at least work without throwing errors. The array driver, as it suggests, stores all the session data in a standard PHP array so everything is erased as soon as the request is completed.

Comment: `\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class` requires sessions too.